# Is there exist an additive but unbounded function?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I just learned that the function that is additive and bounded near $0$ on Real has the only form of $f(x)=cx$, where $c$ is a constant number. We say that a function $f$ is additive iff $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y), \forall x, y \in \mathbb{R}$. We say it is bounded near $0$ iff there exists $a>0$ and $M>0 $ such that if $|x|<a$, then $|f(x)|<M$. I wonder whether there exist an additive function but is unbounded everywhere?
Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: A strange example can be made the following way. Consider R as a vector space over Q. It has a Hamel basis (this follows from the axiom of choice); take any coordinate function corresponding to this basis. It is additive by definition, but it is clearly not of the form `c x` (as it's values are rationals), so it is unbounded.

Comment: I was thinking of the same example.  I wonder if one exists without (any form of) AC.

Comment: @lisyarus make it an answer?

Comment: @Tom sure, made an answer.

Answer (score 1):

A non-constructive example of an unbounded additive function can be achieved as follows.

Consider $\mathbb{R}$ to be a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ (a continuum-dimensioned one). By the axiom of choice, it has a [Hamel basis](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HamelBasis.html). Take any of the coordinate functions corresponding to this basis. It is additive as any coordinate function, but it cannot be represented as $f(x) = c x$, as it's codomain is $\mathbb{Q}$, consequently, it is unbounded.